# How to open the Document files e.g(.pdf,.doc,.docx) in ios mobile when a button action using swift3.0?

Tags: ios, swift3, document, uidocument, uidocumentmenuvc

I need to open `UIDocumentPickerViewController` and It should allow user to select all type of files. ie.(.pdf,.doc)files I used `UIDocumentPickerViewController` method. 
my Code:

`UIDocumentPickerDelegate, UIDocumentMenuDelegate` in my class declaration

//upload file

```
func OpenFile(){

    let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePNG),String(kUTTypeImage)], in: .import)
    importMenu.delegate = self
    importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
@available(iOS 8.0, *)
public func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {        
    let cico = url as URL
    print("The Url is : \(cico)")

    do {
        let weatherData = try NSData(contentsOf: cico, options: NSData.ReadingOptions())
        print(weatherData)
        let activityItems = [weatherData]
        let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
        if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .phone {
            self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
        }
        else {
            let popup = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: activityController)
            popup.present(from: CGRect(x: CGFloat(self.view.frame.size.width / 2), y: CGFloat(self.view.frame.size.height / 4), width: CGFloat(0), height: CGFloat(0)), in: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: .any, animated: true)
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

    //optional, case PDF -> render
    //displayPDFweb.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: cico) as URLRequest)      


}

@available(iOS 8.0, *)
public func documentMenu(_ documentMenu:     UIDocumentMenuViewController, didPickDocumentPicker documentPicker: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {

    documentPicker.delegate = self
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)        
} 


func documentPickerWasCancelled(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController) {

    print(" cancelled by user")

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)        

}
```

In this code the app will crash. the reason is `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'You cannot initialize a UIDocumentPickerViewController except by the initWithDocumentTypes:inMode: and initWithURL:inMode: initializers.`

I don't know how to initialise the `initWithDocumentTypes:inMode.` I'm new to iOS any one help me???
can you please help me..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Swift 3*, 4*,

To open document and select any document, you are using `UIDocumentPickerViewController` then all documents presented in your iCloud, Files and in Google Drive will be shown if Google Drive is connected in user device. Then selected document need to download in your app and from there you can show it in `WKWebView`,

```
   @IBAction func uploadNewResumeAction(_ sender: Any) {

  /*  let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", "com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers", "com.apple.iwork.keynote.key","public.image", "com.apple.application", "public.item","public.data", "public.content", "public.audiovisual-content", "public.movie", "public.audiovisual-content", "public.video", "public.audio", "public.text", "public.data", "public.zip-archive", "com.pkware.zip-archive", "public.composite-content", "public.text"], in: .import) */

    let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.text", "com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", "public.data"], in: .import)

    documentPicker.delegate = self
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

   extension YourViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate{


      func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {

                let cico = url as URL
                print(cico)
                print(url)

                print(url.lastPathComponent)

                print(url.pathExtension)

               }
   }
```

Note: If you intend to select all files the you have to use following code:

```
  let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", "com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers", "com.apple.iwork.keynote.key","public.image", "com.apple.application", "public.item","public.data", "public.content", "public.audiovisual-content", "public.movie", "public.audiovisual-content", "public.video", "public.audio", "public.text", "public.data", "public.zip-archive", "com.pkware.zip-archive", "public.composite-content", "public.text"], in: .import)
```

In your action method.

Comment: Hi Abhishek then how to upload the document to the server.

Comment: @mouni well, it is very easy, if you can select document from `UIDocumentPickerViewController ` then you will get file path `print(url)` from above code of mine. and you need to look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754252/how-to-open-a-link-to-a-pdf-with-wkwebview/47754483#47754483

Then that file need to upload like any other like to upload images into the server.

Comment: I have an error Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application initializing document picker is missing the iCloud entitlement. Is com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers set?'

Comment: @mouni when did you find the crash ? in which operation ?

Comment: I use uiactionsheet. when I click file action it will be crash. I my fileAction i can use  let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.text", "com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", "public.data"], in: .import)

    documentPicker.delegate = self
    present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @mouni turn off the iColoud thing, to do so, go through this image: https://imgur.com/a/ntubG

Comment: I all so off the iColoud. still I have an error *** Assertion failure in -[UIDocumentPickerViewController _commonInitWithCompletion:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3600.9.1/UIDocumentPickerViewController.m:91
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application initializing document picker is missing the iCloud entitlement. Is com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers set?'

Comment: @mouni well in that case i need to look into your code, else it will be not possible to solve this by seeing only this error msg.

Comment: can you please try this link [https://www.dropbox.com/s/f3i4k5f61rbnuko/AddressProofVC.swift?dl=0]

Comment: @mouni when did you finding the crash ? when you calling `actionSheet` delegate method, at that time? Here I can not compile your code by this way.

Comment: I click File button the crash.

Comment: func OpenFile(){ } function.                                                                          the takefile() is no need it. I hide the function.

Comment: Well, according to your code you are calling your `OpenFile()` from `actionSheet`, and when `OpenFile()` get called, it get crashed according to you. Well here i did not find anything unusual, except you can try `DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("Async1")
}`
Also, can you say if compiler entering in `didPickDocumentAt` this delegate method ?

Comment: @mouni you can try this `func OpenFile(){
        
         self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
      
        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.text", "com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", "public.data"], in: .import)
        
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }` Replace this code with your `OpenFile(){}`

Comment: I replace it but still Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application initializing document picker is missing the iCloud entitlement. Is com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers set?'

Comment: @mouni well without compiling it is impossible to detect the main problem. At least I can't.

Comment: Thank you so much I got it...  finally I on the iCloud Driver. it's working fine. thank you Abhishek :)

Comment: How can we make single selection enable ?
Making documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = true is only making select all documents at once but how can we enable single and multiple selection with those side thumbnails as default property of image selection as well in iOS ?

Answer (score 17):

To open the specific document files of **(.pdf, .doc, .docx)** using `UIDocumentPickerViewController` in Swift:
documentTypes would be

import `import MobileCoreServices`

```
["com.microsoft.word.doc","org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document", kUTTypePDF as String]
```

**Example:**

```
let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["com.microsoft.word.doc","org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document", kUTTypePDF as String], in: UIDocumentPickerMode.import) 
importMenu.delegate = self 
self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Yes, it for xls file.

Comment: What type we have to used for "Excel" file.

Answer (score 15):

> Actually, instead of **WebView** you could also use the **QuickLook**
>   **Framework**, which is designed for this specific purpose. You just pass
>   the location of the file and conform to the protocols. It will present
>   a view controller with the document inside.

*It supports the following file:*

**- iWork documents (Pages, Numbers and Keynote)**

**- Microsoft Office documents (as long as they’ve been created with Office 97 or any other newer version)**

**- PDF files**

**- Images**

**- Text files**

**- Rich-Text Format documents**

**- Comma-Separated Value files (csv)**

[**Here**](https://www.appcoda.com/quick-look-framework/) is a tutorial by APPCODA, that describes the same.

and

[**Here**](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/UsingtheQuickLookFramework.html) is the tutorial provided by Apple OBJ-C version.

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped !

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The QuickLook Framework is the best way to render documents, not using WebView.

Answer (score 1):

`UIDocumentPickerViewController.init(documentTypes:in:)` and `kUTType___` were deprecated in iOS 14 and 15 respectively. Here's how to achieve the same on newer versions of iOS:

```swift
let contentTypes: [UTType] = [
    .init(filenameExtension: "doc")!,
    .init(filenameExtension: "docx")!,
    .pdf
]

let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController.init(forOpeningContentTypes: contentTypes, asCopy: true)
documentPicker.delegate = self
present(documentPicker, animated: true)
```

Comment: What type we have to used for "Excel" file

Comment: @Jain_Taresh `UTType.init(filenameExtension: "xls")` and `UTType.init(filenameExtension: "xlsx")` I believe.