# How we View & Share the downloaded files in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, file, pdf, file-manager

In my project i saved the PDF file from NSData & displayed in WebView it working fine, i checked with Simulator & find in app folder the file is successfully downloaded without any corruption.

Here my problem is how can i view the file in real device(iPhone & iPad too) & share the files. like android file manager..

there is no option to view & share(Mail , Whatsapp etc..) the files?

my code below

```
 NSError *errr;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Folder"];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&errr]; //Create folder

        [data writeToFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", dataPath, @"Report.pdf"] atomically:YES];
    }
 [self.webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Help me..

Answer (score 1):

> Actually, instead of WebView you could also use the QuickLook
>   Framework, which is designed for this specific purpose. You just pass
>   the location of the file and conform to the protocols. It will present
>   a view controller with the document inside and also give you native options to share and open the document in other apps.

Find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47866520/2570153).

Comment: Thanks for your answer... i already worked in QuickLook Framework, but my need is after closing he app in need to view & share files..like android

Comment: yes like that in iOS 11 having the Files app but there my downloaded files are not showing

Comment: actually the files app is almost same as iDrive, it won't show the files as such. You will need to add your files there.