# Shared WebView in UIActivityViewController

Tags: swift, webview, uiactivityviewcontroller

I get a PDF in Json, retrieve it and have it displayed in a webview, but I also need it to be shared with the UIActivityViewController, but when I pass the webview it does not show options available for sharing

I am doing the following:

```
 //I get the json
    if let url = URL(string: "http://10.1.80.106:9000/api/recibo/imprimir?vigencia=2015-06-30") {
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.setValue("application/pdf", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        urlRequest.setValue("aaaabbbccc", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        //i create the webview
        let webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        webView.loadRequest(urlRequest as URLRequest)
        webView.scalesPageToFit = true
        let pdfVC = UIViewController()
        pdfVC.view.addSubview(webView)
        pdfVC.title = "Recibo de Pagamento"
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(pdfVC, animated: true)


        //instantiate the UIActivityViewController for the share, and step the WebView as parameter
        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [(webView.request?.url?.absoluteString) as Any], applicationActivities: [])

        if let popoverController = vc.popoverPresentationController {
            popoverController.sourceView = self.view
            popoverController.sourceRect = self.view.bounds
        }
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Actually, instead of WebView you could also use the QuickLook Framework, which is designed for this specific purpose. You just pass
>   the location of the file and conform to the protocols. It will present
>   a view controller with the document inside. You can also have the native options to share the file.**

Check out **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47866520/2570153)** answer about it's implementation and example.