# is there a search engine for finding the data in documents folder in iOS?

Tags: ios

I am having files(can be PDF,html....) in document folder in iOS? If user want to search data/string then we need to check which all the files that are having the data/string inside it. Do we have any search engine which returns the files that are having the user entered data/string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open the Document files e.g(.pdf,.doc,.docx) in ios mobile when a button action using swift3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865646/how-to-open-the-document-files-e-g-pdf-doc-docx-in-ios-mobile-when-a-button)

Comment: its not about opening the file, we need to identify the string that is exiting in files list.

Comment: I am afraid you need to do indexing yourselves with tools like Aloglia.

Comment: Just list all the files out into an array with `FileManager` then search from it?

Comment: It seems Algolia is for JSON, need for HTML