# WKWebView not loading pdf

Tags: pdf, wkwebview

I have an url to a pdf that doesn't show the pdf extension like:

https://www.myserver.com/lsdhfasjkdhfo2387407402374

The url can be opened in safari but doesn't in my WKWebView

I implemented the WKNavigationDelegate and receive a callback on func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) which I allow. But then nothing happens.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are directly trying to open the pdf from URL into WKWebView it will not work because of restriction added to WKWebView for device protection.

You can refer this article [How to open a Link to a PDF with wkwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754252/how-to-open-a-link-to-a-pdf-with-wkwebview) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

For previewing pdf file in WKWebView you have to upload pdf on sever and open its link on webview.