# PDF file not showing ios

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, wkwebview

I have few pdf files at firebase server that i need to show to the users in the app.
But the problem is, it doesn't show the pdf files neither in webview nor in WKWebView.
I tried the following code snippets but neither worked.

```
if let url = URL(string: urlString){
  // First Approach          
   if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
       webView.load(data, mimeType: "application/pdf", characterEncodingName: "", baseURL: url)
   }
            // Second Approach 
            let req = URLRequest(url: url)
            self.webView.load(req)
}
```

Here is one of the urls.
[Pdf file](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mini-muslims.appspot.com/o/Books%2F-M5HgblfIM4jvINka3j2?alt=media&token=745ca3e3-b18b-4b2a-96c1-e791f977c2df)

I used the PDFKit as well but that also didn't work. Here is the log when i try to load it into webview.

```
2020-05-21 21:06:01.561593+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-05-21 21:06:10.383853+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-05-21 21:06:10.384063+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-05-21 21:06:13.050745+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748634] Task <5CBC8251-89EC-4DCD-A9A0-E794B3AEB6EC>.<0> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -999 [1:89])
2020-05-21 21:06:18.123494+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-05-21 21:06:18.123672+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-05-21 21:06:18.173099+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-05-21 21:06:18.173315+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-05-21 21:06:19.260676+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-05-21 21:06:19.260878+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-05-21 21:06:22.607212+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-05-21 21:06:22.607351+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-05-21 21:06:23.080709+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-05-21 21:06:23.080916+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-05-21 21:06:28.736644+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-05-21 21:06:28.736875+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2020-05-21 21:06:36.769000+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
2020-05-21 21:06:36.769220+0500 Mini Muslims[41242:748632] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
```

The pdf never loads. What could be the possible issue. Please guide me so that i can resolve this issue.

Comment: I think it's duplicate with this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754252/how-to-open-a-link-to-a-pdf-with-wkwebview

Comment: @DanielWijono that solution is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to load the `pdf` file in `WKWebView`

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

   var WKwebView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
               let userContentController: WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()
               let conf = WKWebViewConfiguration()
               conf.userContentController = userContentController
               WKwebView = WKWebView (frame: CGRect( x: 0, y: 60, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 60 ), configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
               WKwebView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
               WKwebView.uiDelegate = self
               WKwebView.scrollView.bounces = false
               WKwebView.scrollView.delegate = self;
               view.addSubview(WKwebView)

                var request : URLRequest!
                let PDFURL = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mini-muslims.appspot.com/o/Books%2F-M5HgblfIM4jvINka3j2?alt=media&token=745ca3e3-b18b-4b2a-96c1-e791f977c2df";
                let url : URL = URL(string: PDFURL as String)!
                request = URLRequest (url: url);
                WKwebView.load(request)

    }
}
```

Comment: Then why is it not working for me? I copied the exact code as yours and it didn't work for me.

Comment: let me send you console log.

Comment: Try loading the file URL in safari , is it loading there ?

Comment: Yes, it is loading. And now it has started to load in the app as well. No change done. Same code as yours and now working fine. Maybe it was the issue with the simulator?

Comment: May be some network issues . Anyways , good it started working