# How to open the pdf files or downloading from webView to native app swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, webview

How we can open, downloading the pdf file from webView to native app? Basically all functionality done in react and we calling this from webView when click on pdf file in webView I'm getting the url of pdf file.Can anyone tell me best approach for opening the pdf file? Or when user open the pdf file I want a close button on pdf file when user click on close button pdf file will be close and get back to the app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a Link to a PDF with wkwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754252/how-to-open-a-link-to-a-pdf-with-wkwebview)

Comment: @ohglstr When user click on webView I'm getting the url.So how I can open the pdf file through this url also I want a close button on pdf file when user click on button the pdf will be close.I think you get my point.

Comment: Your first question was "Can anyone tell me best approach for opening the pdf file?" - linked issue does that. Regarding close button: first of all it's good to post one question over time, second - you need to be more specific. What did you try so far? what didn't work? Because if, lets say, I suggest you close webview and reopen it with your app - it's probably not a useful answer. But it answers your question